# Filtering in subreport

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have encountered issues with using "filtering menus" in report during development of database aplication for my employer.

For my filtering options I created buttons with OnClick Event:

```
DoCmd.GoToControl "MyReportField"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
```

These buttons are embedded in subreport. Initial thought was to create buttons, similar to the one in ribbon, with filtering options (in final stages of development I am planning to disable/hide Access ribbon for users). I created 5 buttons, 3 for fields with data type Text, 1 with data type Date and 1 with Boolean data type.

To quote a classic, the buttons "are misbehaving." When I test their function in form in form view, the "BooleanFilterBtn" on click already doesn't display Yes/No options (or something similar), but displays 2 numeric values (like -24441 or -29696). And filter is not working whatsoever.

Another problem arises when I try to have active more than one filter at a time. Date field filter and one of the Text field filters are working when combined with another filter option. But after using one of the two remaining Text field filters, when I click any other of the filtering buttons, the FilterMenu becomes blank.

Worth noting is that right-clicking on given field in report works without issues, but not the way I want.

Given these rather odd behaviours I think I am missing something. Is there a way how to make FilterMenus work the way as familiar from the ribbon? If not, is there any other option with similar design, options that I could try out?

Additional info:

Subreport is connected with form through "MyIDField." Both subreport and form have query data source, already saved.

All field names and data types are matching.

EDIT: Also I should have written that the FilterBtns doesn't work if I open the subreport separately, they work only when I open form (with subreport in it), eventhough the FilterBtns are using only controls from the report.

EDIT2: Code behind filter button filtering Boolean data type (boolean data are in Report in form of Yes/No check-fields, as mentioned in June7 comment bellow):

```
Private Sub btn_FiltrGarant_Click()
DoCmd.GoToControl "Garant"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub
```

When I change this code to:

```
Private Sub btn_FiltrGarant_Click() 
Me.Garant.SetFocus 
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu 
End Sub
```

Brings no effect, only that the loading time of actual FilterMenu takes a bit longer.

Example for Text data type field:

```
Private Sub btn_FiltrRzh_Click()
DoCmd.GoToControl "ZkracenyNazev"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub
```

Changing code in the same manner:

```
Private Sub btn_FiltrRzh_Click() 
Me.ZkracenyNazev.SetFocus 
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu 
End Sub
```

Brings no effect too.

May it be that the FilterMenu is not meant to/available to be used in reports? Or may it be disabled in default settings of Access?

Because also the situation, that if I open the Report separately (not in form as a subreport, but just as report by itself in report view), using any of the FilterBtns gives me RunTime error 2046, that the action GoToControl is not available. Changing to SetFocus eliminates the error, but the button doesn't bring up any FilterMenu at all. But these issues are valid only if I open report separately (which is not my interest), but might be helpfull as information.

Right now, I don't know where the problem could be. Anything I could think of was data type/naming mismatch, but that's not the case.

FINAL EDIT: After almost a month (there were holydays) of trying and searching for a way how to make this setup work I decided to switch from subreport to subform, in which I will try to obtain the same functionality.
Maybe just reports are not supposed to be handled the way I wanted to.

Just out of courtesy I am putting June7 answer as verifiedfor the time spent on helping me.

Thank you.

Comment: Subreport or subform? Maybe a screenshot would help illustrate.

Comment: You have a report embedded on a form?

Comment: @Parfait I am sorry, I may have written it in a confusing way. It is subreport in form, the "FilterBtn"s are inserted in "PageHeader" of the subreport.
I am not sure how to upload screenshot here.
I try to illustrate the situation by describing how I created this solution. First I created "MyForm," then I (separately) created "MyReport." In design view of "MyForm" I dragged "MyReport" from Acces object list (bar on the left side of default Acces view) into "MyForm" layout. Then I have set the connecting field for these two objects and later in development I created "FilterBtn"s.

Comment: @June Please note comment above, I hope the answer is there. Maybe I havent used the right proverb, my english is not too good.
Also I couldnt put two users in comment ping...

Comment: I have never used acCmdFilterMenu nor GoToControl so just did some testing with both. Code behind report works just fine as subreport. I prefer `SetFocus` as in: `Me.controlname.SetFocus`. This works whether the report is open independent or as a sub object.

Comment: For alternate approach review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: @June7 First of all, sorry for misspelling your user name last time.
Did you have in mind changing the code I posted like that:

`Private Sub btn_FilterBtn_Click()
Me.ControlName.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterMenu
End Sub`
If thats the case, my issues are persisting, which means I might be doing something wrong/uncorrect somewhere else. I check all I can think of again, but also do you have any suggestions what could cause the malfuntions described in question?
Thank you, Tomáš

Comment: Did you use your actual control name in place of ControlName? Edit question to show complete actual code if you want help analyzing it. I cannot replicate the issue you describe so have no idea what is causing it. Menu for my Yes/No field shows options (Select All) and IsSelected.

Comment: @June7 Edited question as you requested. I put in question code for Boolean data type filter and for Text data type filter. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @June7 Please note my final edit. Thanks again, Tomáš

Comment: I found the same issue with subform as with subreport and applied the same solution.

Comment: I have no trouble filtering subform the way descriped in the question.
The issues on my side are happening only when working with subreport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why your yes/no field displays 2 numeric values like -24441 or -29696 in the filter menu. Regardless, not able to get the filter menu to act on a yes/no field at all. However, get around that with an expression in report RecordSource query that changes the Yes/No field from Boolean to text values and use the calculated field in report design, like:

`SELECT *, IIf([fieldname], "Yes", "No") AS IsSomethingTrue FROM tablename;`

Use `Me.controlname.SetFocus` instead of `GoToControl` so the report will open independently or as a sub object.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be careful how you refer to a Report object that is within a subForm container. They do not behave the same as subforms in many ways.

Even a simple refresh is actually difficult to achieve, as reports are not meant to be *dynamic* like a form.

To refer to it in VBA you have to use the full form syntax;

```
[Forms]![MainFormName].[Form]![subReportHolderName].Requery
```

Using the normal Me.blah.blah reference will not work with a form embedded report. Note that you refer to the container - NOT the report object.

Comment: These work for me: `Forms!subReportHolderName.Requery` and if the code is behind the report `Me.Requery`.

Comment: @Minty Sorry, I am a bit confused... I did not used such references whatsoever, I simply created those buttons "within" the report itself, then moved it as a whole into the form.
Are you suggestinig, that I should have created the buttons not within report (subreport), but within the form itself and then have requery procedure to "refresh" the subreport?

Comment: @June7 Could you elaborate on your comment?
It might be the mistake I am making, but I am not using any of this syntax in the code behind the buttons. Also I have no issues with the report results/viewing.
My problem is in viewing the FilterMenus, which are in case of boolean values showing values with no sense.
And, in case of two text-field filters, after apllying one of them, other FilterMenus become blank-without any filtering options, even though there should be some.

Comment: My comments weer based on the buttons NOT being on the report but on the form that the report object was contained in. So they possibly aren't relevant. I would still say that using the syntax June specified would not work on a form / subreport form I was working on, but it was pretty complicated so it may have been something else.